# Iphone invalid date from string

Tags: iphone, date

I face to problem with IPhone and date.

When I run this code:

```
const date = new Date('2022-07-04 15:29:00');
alert(date);
```

But with Iphone chrome I Get following error

```
Invalid date
```

With other devices (android, windows, linux) a get correct date.

Does somebody know what kind of problem is in IPhone?

Comment: That's likely caused by your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in date format. Date format has to be in ISO-8061 format.